# Concatenar un string a un elemento de un ArrayList JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo mi siguiente `ArrayList`, deseo concatenar una cadena (String) a el elemento del `ArrayList` que contenga "11":

```
        List<String> llaveprimarianumero = new ArrayList<String>();
        llaveprimarianumero.add("11 prueba");
        llaveprimarianumero.add("22");
        llaveprimarianumero.add("33");
        llaveprimarianumero.add("44");

        String valoradicional = " prueba";

        for (int i = 0; i < llaveprimarianumero.size(); i++) {
            if (llaveprimarianumero.get(i).contains("11")) {
                // Aqui concatenar a ese elemento que tenga 11 otro string en el mismo indice
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, llaveprimarianumero, "Pruebas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

¿ Como puedo realizar esta concatenación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo estas realizando casi correctamente, al obtener el valor que contiene "11" concatena el valor adicional:

```
llaveprimarianumero.get(i) + valoradicional
```

y este valor lo vuelves a insertar en la posición del `List` usando el método [set(int index, String valor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-), recuerda que i contiene el indice de la posición.

```
llaveprimarianumero.set(i, llaveprimarianumero.get(i) + valoradicional);
```

Este sería el ejemplo mostrando el valor en el Dialogo:

```
List<String> llaveprimarianumero = new ArrayList<String>();
    llaveprimarianumero.add("11 prueba");
    llaveprimarianumero.add("22");
    llaveprimarianumero.add("33");
    llaveprimarianumero.add("44");

    String valoradicional = " prueba";

    for (int i = 0; i < llaveprimarianumero.size(); i++) {
        if (llaveprimarianumero.get(i).contains("11")) {
            // Aqui concatenar a ese elemento que tenga 11 otro string en el mismo indice

           llaveprimarianumero.set(i, llaveprimarianumero.get(i) + valoradicional);

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, llaveprimarianumero.get(i), "Pruebas",  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias ya agrega el String que requería

Comment: Excelente @alexander6896 , saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Intenta utilizando el metodo [`set(int index, E e);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) que actualiza el elemento del index dado en la lista:

```
for (int i = 0; i < llaveprimarianumero.size(); i++) {
      String actual = llaveprimarianumero.get(i);
      if (actual.contains("11")) {
         llaveprimarianumero.set(i, actual + valoradicional);
      }
}
```

Comment: Gracias ya agrega el String que requería

Answer (score 1):

¿Te valdría algo así?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < llaveprimarianumero.size(); i++) {
        String actual = llaveprimarianumero.get(i);
        if (actual.contains("11")) {
           llaveprimarianumero.set(i, actual + "MI CADENA A CONCATENAR");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias ya agrega el String que requería